# Stash: how to overwrite a variable in set_list?

Tags: stash

Is there a way to define default values in set_list?

Basically, I want to set 3 variable to:

```
{stash:var_run_here}no{/stash:var_run_here}
{stash:var_type}none{/stash:var_type}
{stash:var_title}{url_title}{/stash:var_title}
```

Then overwrite them, depending on a playa value or checkbox values further in the set_list grouping. Something like:

```
    {if is_global == 'y'}
            {stash:var_run_here}global{/stash:var_run_here}
    {if:else}
        {run_on_these_pages}
            {exp:switchee variable = "{url_title}" parse="inward"}
                {case value="{segment_2}"}
                    {stash:var_run_here}yep{/stash:var_run_here}
                {/case}
            {/exp:switchee}
        {/run_on_these_pages}
    {/if}

    {exclude_from_these_sections}
        {exp:switchee variable = "{option_name}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="{url_title}"}
                {stash:var_run_here}yep{/stash:var_run_here}
            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exclude_from_these_sections}
```

So that this is the get_list part:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="fma_list" parse_conditionals="yes" unique="yes" process="end" orderby="var_type" sort="asc" limit="999"}
  Title: {var_title}<br>
  Run On This Page: {var_run_here}<br>
  Type: {var_type}<br>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but what's the problem you're having ?

Comment: Can you also include where you `{exp:channel:entries}` tag is included in your code?

Comment: i think you should parse_tags and parse_conditionals on the set_lest part.

Comment: this is actually not working for me with stash in EE3.
```
{stash:url}my default title{/stash:url}
//new list entry created here
{stash:url}{url_title}{/stash:url}
``` when I want to overwrite a varible like in the code example, a new entry in my list is created. anybody has the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just put those default values at the top. Those values will be replaced if they're set later in the order.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="fma_list" ... }
    {exp:channel:entries ... }
        {stash:var_run_here}no{/stash:var_run_here}
        {stash:var_type}none{/stash:var_type}
        {stash:var_title}{url_title}{/stash:var_title}
        {if is_global == 'y'}
            {stash:var_run_here}global{/stash:var_run_here}
        {if:else}
            {run_on_these_pages}
                {exp:switchee variable = "{url_title}" parse="inward"}
                    {case value="{segment_2}"}
                        {stash:var_run_here}yep{/stash:var_run_here}
                    {/case}
                {/exp:switchee}
            {/run_on_these_pages}
        {/if}

        {exclude_from_these_sections}
            {exp:switchee variable = "{option_name}" parse="inward"}
                {case value="{url_title}"}
                    {stash:var_run_here}yep{/stash:var_run_here}
                {/case}
           {/exp:switchee}
        {/exclude_from_these_sections}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```